# Delta method for asymptotic variance

Tags: poisson-distribution, variance, bernoulli-numbers, delta-method

Let $X_i$ be i.i.d. r.v. with $\sim Exp(\lambda)$ and for n to $\infty$
$$\sqrt{n} \cdot (Z_n - \theta) \overset{d}{\to} N(0,\sigma^2) $$

$\tilde{\lambda} = - ln(\bar{Y_n})$, where $Y_i = 1 \{X_i = 0\}$ -> Bernoulli

I am looking to find the **asymptotic variance $V(\hat{\lambda})$**

I can see that Y has the property of a Bernoulli
$Y_i = 1_{(X_i=0)} = $ 1 if $(X_i = 0)$ and $= 0$ if $(X_i = 1)$

Applying the delta method (via Tayler expansion)

$$\sqrt{n}(g(Z_n)-g(\theta)) \overset{d}{\to} N(0, g'(\theta)^2 * \sigma^2)$$

$$\sqrt{n}(g(\bar{Y_n})-g(E(Y))) \overset{d}{\to} N(0, g'(E(Y))^2 * Var(Y))$$

Via the exponential pdf I calculate $P(X=0) = \lambda*e^{-\lambda*0} = \lambda$, which I will take as my $E[Y]$ and plug this term into the Bernoulli variance formula $p*(1-p)$: $$Var(Y) = \lambda*(1-\lambda) = \lambda-\lambda^2$$

Now for the term $g'(E[Y])^2$ I take the derivative of $g(E[Y]) = -ln(E[Y])$ and square it: $g'(E[Y])^2 = \frac{1}{E[Y]^2}$

With $E[Y] = \lambda$ calculated before, I get $g'(E[Y])^2 = \frac{1}{\lambda^2}$

Plugging both terms together I get $$V(\hat{\lambda}) = \frac{1}{\lambda^2} * (\lambda-\lambda^2) = \frac{1}{\lambda}-1$$

Since this solution is **incorrect**, where am I mistaken?

Comment: $Y_i=1$ a.s., since $X_i>0$ a.s. Hence $\bar{Y}_n=1$ a.s. This seems a bit odd to me. In particular, $\hat{\lambda}$ does not converge to $\lambda.$

Comment: Maybe you want to assume the $X_i$ are iid Poisson with expectation $\lambda$, instead?

Comment: The distribution should be Exp($\lambda$) with mean $1/\lambda$ and variance $1/<lambda^2$. I might guess the error lies in the calculation of the derivative, but I can't see where.

Comment: If the $X_i$ have a continuous distribution, your recipe for $Y_i$ is nonsense.  Where did you get this problem from?

Comment: I am doing a course in mathematics of statistics. Just updated the text, I hope this makes it easier to understand. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Maybe my calculation of E[Y] is mistaken.. But I do not see another way. Happy to hear any suggestions.